# Let $X\subset Y$ be a dense inclusion of reflexive Banach spaces. Then is $C_c^\infty(\Omega;X)\subset C_c^\infty(\Omega;Y)$ dense?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $X$, $Y$ be reflexive Banach spaces, and let $\imath:X\hookrightarrow Y$ be a bounded inclusion with dense image. Then for any domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ we may define $C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega;X)$ to be the (Fréchet)-smooth functions $\Omega\to X$ with compact support, with the usual inductive limit topology, and likewise for $C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega;Y)$. Then $\imath$ clearly induces a continuous inclusion $$\imath_*:C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega;X)\hookrightarrow C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega;Y)$$ however, it is not at all clear to me if $\imath_*$ will have dense image. I suspect it won't, though I have yet to find a counterexample. So, does it have dense image, and if so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C^\infty_c(\Omega, X) = C^\infty_c(\Omega,\mathbb R){\bar\otimes} X$ completed inductive tensor product which agrees with the projective tensor product since $C^\infty_c(\Omega,\mathbb R)$ is nuclear. Do the same for $Y$. Finite rank tensors are dense in $C^\infty_c(\Omega,\mathbb R){\bar\otimes} Y$ and these can be approximated by finite rank tensors in $C^\infty_c(\Omega,\mathbb R){\bar\otimes} X$.

Comment: One must be careful with the inductive tensor product. Even for nuclear spaces it does not necessarily coincide with the projective tensor product. This however is not needed for the argument.

Comment: Incidentally, could a similar technique be used to show that $$C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega)'\bar{\otimes}X=\mathcal{L}(C_{\mathrm c}^\infty(\Omega),X)$$ for any Banach space $X$, assuming such a thing is true?